# How to assign values to multiple variables using ternary operator in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, variable-assignment, ternary-operator

I have done following code in codeigniter using if statement for fulfilling my logic, but I want to do it using a ternary operator:

```
<?php
     $payment_via = $this->input->post('payment');

     if($payment_via == "bank"){
        $this->page_data['message_type'] = "paid_via_bank"; 
        $this->page_data['message'] = "You have Successfully Subscribed plan via Bank cheque.";
     }else{
        $this->page_data['message_type'] = "paid_via_online"; 
        $this->page_data['message'] = "You have Successfully Subscribed plan via Online payment.";            
     }

     $this->load->view('payment/checkout_msg', $this->page_data);
```

I know that I can assign a value to a single variable, but **I want to assign multiple variables in a ternary expression**. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think the readability and maintainability will improve using a ternary expression. I should keep your current code.

Comment: Since you don't have multiple conditions, you can set `$msg_type` and `$msg` with default values as `paid_via_online` and `...via Online payment.` respectively. `else` can be removed.

Comment: Moreover `$msg` and `$msg_type` variables are redundant if you're not going to use it below the `load->view`. Assign the values directly to the `page_data` keys.

Comment: sure @ViswalingaSuryaS nice suggestions i will do it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i was trying and playing with many workarounds i have found one which works absolutely as i want which is as below:

```
<?php 

      $payment_via = $this->input->post('payment');
      ($payment_via == "bank") ? (($this->page_data['message_type'] = "paid_via_bank") && ($$this->page_data['message'] = "You have Successfully Subscribed plan via Bank cheque.")) : (($this->page_data['message_type'] = "paid_via_online") && ( $this->page_data['message'] = 'You have Successfully Subscribed plan via Online payment.'));                        

      $this->load->view('demo/checkout_msg', $this->page_data);
```

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: Whilst both code examples will work and I presume does the same thing, in terms of readability, the first example will be far easier on the eyes. This in turn means any amendments to the code are easier to implement and any potential bugs, easier to spot.

Each to their own!

Comment: Agree with @JimGrant, also this code brings __useless difficulty__.

Comment: And if you try to minimize your code - then you should assign messages __directly__ to `$this->page_data['message_type']` without any intermediate variables.

Comment: @JimGrant, i agree that it will be not a nice way, but atleast i found something new so i have shared it here.